# Simple but require bit manipulation Python Hex and INT

Tags: python, arrays, string, int

I have an integer - say for example

```
a = 12345
b = hex(a)
```

I have to send this to an MCU in a specific format. First I have to convert it into hex. which I did and it gives me --- 0x3039;

I need an array something like this - [0x39, 0x30]

Currently I am converting the whole number into a string then to a list and then doing some element of list manipulation.

I am hoping there is something easier. Which can be done in a line or two? It should work even with the following numbers - 1234, 123, 12, 1- Implying it should work from single digit to five digit numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a list of hex strings with number as little endian bytes:

```
a=12345
l = [hex(a&0xff),hex(a>>8)]  # little endian format, as hex string
print(l)
```

gives:

```
['0x39', '0x30']
```

note the quotes, it is not possible to print `[0x39, 0x30]`. If you want the integer values, just do

```
l = [a&0xff,a>>8]  # little endian, format as bytes
```

which gives:

```
[57, 48]
```

and BTW:

```
[0x39, 0x30]==[57, 48] => True
```

it's just that representation/print of integers in a list is in decimal :)